# Why $N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\alpha))=N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\beta))$ implies $(\alpha)=( \beta)$ or $(\alpha)=( \beta')$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratic imaginary number field.

Let $ \alpha, \beta \in R_K$. **And suppose $(\alpha)$ is prime ideal of ring of integers of $K$.**

My question is, why $N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\alpha))$$=$$N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\beta))$ implies $(\alpha)=( \beta)$ or $(\alpha)=( \beta')$ where $ \beta'$ is $Gal(K/ \Bbb{Q})$-conjugate of $ \alpha$?

I know $N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\alpha))=｜N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)｜$ and $N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}((\beta))=｜N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}(\beta)｜$, so $N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)=±N_{K/ \Bbb{Q}}(\beta)$.

But I cannot proceed from here. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: It doesn't, try with $K=\Bbb{Q}(i), \alpha=(2+i)(4+i), \beta=(2+i)(4-i)$

Comment: Where is this statement given?

Comment: @Reuns Thank you for your helpful comment, I missed important condition, I edited.

Comment: @Aivint Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves written by Silverman, chapter 5.

Comment: There is either one ($(p)$) or two ( $\alpha$ and its complex conjugate) prime ideal containing $N((\alpha))$

Comment: @reuns How can I deduce $(α)=(β)(β')$ ? $(α)⊇(β)(β')$ is ok, but I'm stuck with showing $⊂$.

Comment: Your comments are confused. Also you need to assume that $\beta\in O_K$ (do you understand the difference between $K$ and $O_K$ and their ideals?)

Comment: Ofcourse, I do, I don't get why my comment is confused, once $αR_K=(βR_K)(β'R_K)$・・・① is shown, $(α)=(β)or (β')$. I want to prove ① but $⊆$ is not clear to me.

Comment: $αR_K=(βR_K)(β'R_K)$ doesn't make much sense.  You have to consider the factorization of $(p)$ with $p$ the prime number dividing $N((\alpha))$.